# transpose a list in python

Tags: python, list, transpose

input file.csv

```
['NE,PORT,EVENT,TIME,VALUE',
'NODE,13,MAX,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-10.9', 
'NODE,13,MIN,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-11.0', 
'NODE,13,CUR,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-10.9', 
'NODE,13,MAX,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-12.9', 
'NODE,13,MIN,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-10.0', 
'NODE,13,CUR,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-12.9']
```

python code:

```
intext=open('file.csv', 'r')
check=intext.readlines()
for lista in check:
    lista_split=lista.split(",")
    lista_split.extend(['MAX','MIN','CUR'])
    lista_index=[0,1,2,3,4]
    lista_index.extend([5,6,7])
    contents=list(lista_split[i] for i in lista_index)
    if contents[2]==('MAX'):
        contents[5] = contents[4])
    elif contents[2]==('MIN'):
        contents[6] = contents[4])
    elif contents[2]==('CUR'):
        contents[7] = contents[4])
    contents.remove(contents[2])
    contents.remove(contents[4])
    print(contents)
```

step1 move EVENT as columns and the corresponding value, step2 clean columns (remove EVENT and VALUE), done!

```
['NE', 'PORT', 'TIME', 'MAX', 'MIN', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST', '-10.9', 'MIN', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST', 'MAX', '-11.0', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST', 'MAX', 'MIN', '-10.9']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST', '-12.9', 'MIN', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST', 'MAX', '-10.0', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST', 'MAX', 'MIN', '-12.9']
```

**target:**

```
['NE', 'PORT', 'TIME', 'MAX', 'MIN', 'CUR']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST', '-10.9', '-11.0', '-10.9']
['NODE', '13', '2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST', '-12.9', '-10.0', '-12.9']
```

Comment: You need to provide some code: how did you solve step1 and step2?

Comment: So your target looks different from what you're asking for in the title. If you want to know how to transpose a list in python you can actually google it: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-list-transpose/ . Please provide more details and some code next time.

Comment: You did not explain in step1 how max,min,cur columns added. It's unclear question.

Comment: how the second `CUR` passed from `-12.9` to `-10.0` is very mysterious. if it's just a typo you don't need all those useless steps

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by creating a pivot table.

```
csv = ['NE,PORT,EVENT,TIME,VALUE',
'NODE,13,MAX,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-10.9', 
'NODE,13,MIN,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-11.0', 
'NODE,13,CUR,2021-08-30 09:15:00+01:00 DST,-10.9', 
'NODE,13,MAX,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-12.9', 
'NODE,13,MIN,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-10.0', 
'NODE,13,CUR,2021-08-30 10:30:00+01:00 DST,-12.9']

csv = [x.split(",") for x in csv]

df = pd.DataFrame(csv[1:], columns=csv[0])
df["VALUE"] = df["VALUE"].astype(float)

df = df.pivot_table("VALUE", ["NE", "PORT", "TIME"], "EVENT")

df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWv6V.png)

Comment: did you use any libraries?

Comment: The only one I used was pandas (you can add "import pandas as pd").

Answer (score 0):

i'll correct just your first step. your logic was good, but there was a lot of confusion due to too many lists

```
for lista in check:
    lista=lista.split(",")
    lista.extend(['MAX','MIN','CUR'])
    if lista[2]==('MAX'):
        lista[5] = lista[4]
    elif lista[2]==('MIN'):
        lista[6] = lista[4]
    elif lista[2]==('CUR'):
        lista[7] = lista[4]
    lista.remove(lista[2])
    lista.remove(lista[3]) #you removed an index before so it's not 4 anymore
    print(lista)
```